# как создать n количество переменных в цикле

Tags: c++

есть цикл

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n;
cin >> n;    
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int a;
}
```

Но проблема в том, что создаётся одна и та же переменная, а необходимо присваивать им разные названия. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Используйте массив динамического размера.

Comment: В чём суть вопроса? Зачем присваивать переменным в цикле разные названия?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак. Когда переменная выходит из области видимости(цикла), она уничтожается.

Самый оптимальный вариант - создать динамический массив на куче. `int* arr = new int[n];`. Создаем указатель на `int`, под который выделяем через оператор `new` `n` ячеек.

Можно и статический, но тогда нужно будет компилятору знать размер массива во время компиляции, то есть, вы не сможете написать такое `int arr[n]`, так как `n` не константа. Тогда надо будет создавать количество элементов заранее, например - на сто ячеек(на запас). Но так не стоит делать.

Comment: Спасибо, но как динамическмй массив поможет создать n переменных?

Comment: ну так массив размера n это и есть n переменных одного типа (по определению)

Comment: А как заполнить массив через cin? Простите, если глупый вопрос

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){ cout << "#" << i << ":  "; cin >> имя_массива[i]; }`